# Convert varchar(32) to bigint

Tags: sql-server, hex, type-conversion, bigint

It is possible to convert a varchar(32) (a hexadecimal string like 0x81f2cf442269e111b99c1cc1deedf59c) to a bigint in sql server ?

I have tried this :

```
select convert(bigint, convert (varbinary(16), '0x81f2cf442269e111b99c1cc1deedf59c', 1))
```

but I am not sure that it works with higher and lower values.

Comment: why do you need to something like that?

Comment: to store this string in a bigint column

Comment: I think these posts may help you http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/01/sql-server-question-how-to-convert-hex-to-decimal/ and http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-hexadecimal-or-binary-to.html

Comment: Tecncially impossible. a 32 hex string is a 16 byte numbe. Bigint only holds 8 b bytes - you can not fit 16 byts in 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is possible to convert a varchar(32) (a hexadecimal string like 
>   0x81f2cf442269e111b99c1cc1deedf59c) to a bigint in sql server ?

2 answers with examples. BOTH fundamentally wrong.

CAN NOT BE DONE. Anyone cares running a basic math check first?

32 hex = 16 bytes.
Biging: 8 bytes.

All your code is one thing - useless. You CANNOT convert a 32 hex string with 16 bytes worth of numbers into a 8 byte number. Only in very few cases (upper 8 bytes all 0).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can go with below ways, would you please try this.

```
DECLARE @HexValue Varchar(32)
SET @HexValue = '0x81f2cf442269e111b99c1cc1deedf59c'

Declare @Query NVARCHAR(100)
Declare @Parameters NVARCHAR(50)
Declare @ReturnValue BIGINT

SET @Query = N'Select @Result = Convert(BIGINT,' + @HexValue + ')'
SET @Parameters = N'@Result BIGINT output'
EXEC MASTER.dbo.Sp_executesql @Query, @Parameters, @ReturnValue OUTPUT

SELECT @ReturnValue
```

Thanks for your time.